# Insert Room data from WorkManager Worker?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following the Android room tutorial.. but have a slightly different requirement than it.  I want to run a job in the background.. and insert a database item there, instead of with a button or on startup like they have it.  I cannot find a way to do this?

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    try {
  
      val appContext = applicationContext

  ......
      
      val newDataItem = DataItem(param1 = "Title", iso_datetime_msg_received = "RIGHTNOW", alert_message = "HI!!!", uuid = 1231)

    
      // THE LINE BELOW IS WHAT I WANT BUT GET AN ERROR 
      // Suspend function 'insert' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function

    CustomRoomDatabase.getDatabase(myContext).dataItemDao().insert(newDataItem)
      return Result.success(result)
    } catch(error: Throwable) {
        Log.i(TAG, "RetrieveDataItemWorker got error:" + error)
        return Result.retry()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your WorkManager class needs to Implement `:CoroutineWorker(context, workerParams)`

then make your `doWork` function a suspend fuction

Comment: do you have a link how to implement?  Still a little new to kotlin android.. thx

Comment: here is an example https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/coroutineworker-use-kotlin-coroutines-in-work-manager/

Comment: your link had some business of adding the WorkManager into the example.. I dropped that.. fiddled a bit with my context references and it worked! Thank you!!

Comment: @tyczj do have implementation of this in java worker class